# Assign two variables from list of tuples in one iteration

Tags: python

I have a function `foo()` that returns a tuple. Let's say `('a', 1)` 
I have an iterable `a` that I want to iterate over and pass every item to that function. 
At the end I need two lists - `r1` and `r2` where `r1` consists of all the first items in the tuples returned from the function. The second list `r2` - the result of all the second items in these tuples.

```
r1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
r2 = [1, 2, 3]
```

I don't like this approach too much:

```
result = [foo(i) for i in a]
r1 = [i[0] for i in result]
r2 = [i[1] for i in result]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function for this.

```
>>> result = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
>>> r1, r2 = zip(*result)
>>> r1
('a', 'b', 'c')
>>> r2
(1, 2, 3)
```

`zip(*result)` *unpacks* each list in `result` and passes them as separate arguments into the `zip` function. It essentially [*transposes*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) the list. It produces a list of two tuples, which then are assigned to `r1` and `r2`.

Comment: @scroll_lock no worries! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just use zip()!

```
result = [foo(i) for i in a]
r1, r2 = zip(*result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The zip function will do you just fine.
Here is a helpful post here that is related directly to that function

[understanding zip function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865640/understanding-zip-function)