# Understanding izip in Python3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, python-2.x

My question is only fo learning purpose, and only on python3.x. In the real life, I will use zip since python3 zip does the same job as python2 izip did (i.e. returning a generator, not the real thing).

in python2, izip is essentially equivalent to the code below (picked from [izip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip%22izip%22), plus some debugging code)

```
def izip(*iterables):
    iterators = map(iter, iterables)
    n = 0
    while iterators:
        x = tuple(map(next, iterators))
        print("at n={}, x={} ".format(n, x))
        yield x
        n += 1
        if n > 10: break
```

Python2 works fine. The output for `izip('abc', 'ABC')` is:

```
at n=0, x=('a', 'A') 
('a', 'A')
at n=1, x=('b', 'B') 
('b', 'B')
at n=2, x=('c', 'C') 
('c', 'C')
```

Python3 enters an infinite loop instead. The reason was explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865640/understanding-zip-function). But there is another point that I cannot understand: python3 yields only the first tuple. This is the output of the same program. Why the bs' and cs' did not show up?:

```
at n=0, x=('a', 'A') 
('a', 'A')
at n=1, x=() 
()
at n=2, x=() 
()
at n=3, x=() 
() etc.
```

My two questions are why Python3 behaves this way? and how to to get this code to work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem lies in the different behavior of `map` between python2 and python3, and specifically in the first call to `map` (`iterators = map(iter, iterables)`).

In python3, `map` returns a generator (or a generator-like object), while in python2, it's a list. This means that after the first call to `tuple(map(next, iterators))`, the `iterators` generator is fully consumed, so in the next iteration, there are no more iterators to work with.

It should work if you change:

```
iterators = map(iter, iterables)
```

to:

```
iterators = list(map(iter, iterables))
```

(which is arguably nicer as `iterators = [ iter(it) for it in iterables ]`)

---

As you pointed out, it now enters an infinite loop. Again, the problem lies in the `map` function, but this time in the second call.

First, let's understand how this implementation works in python2.  Despite having a `while iterators` loop, the loop does not break due to the condition being false, but due to a StopIteration exception being raised by one of the calls to `next`. This exception is propagated to caller's loop, which correctly understand there are no more results.

It might have been intuitive to implement it like this:

```
def izip(*iterables):
    if not iterables: return []
    iterators = map(iter, iterables)
    while True:
        yield tuple(map(next, iterators))
```

Now, the behavior of `map` changed in python3 here too. instead of raising, it "trims" the output:

```
list(map(next, [ iter('ab'), iter('') ]))
=> ['a']
```

Not raising StopIteration leads to an infinite loop.

The solution would be using a list comprehension, which *does* propagate the StopIteration exception.

```
def izip(*iterables):
    if not iterables: return []
    iterators = map(iter, iterables)
    while True:
        yield tuple([ next(it) for it in iterators ])
```

---

Lesson learnt: list comprehensions (and generator expressions) [should be favored](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5426754/2096752) over `map`, `filter`, etc.

Comment: Very subtle indeed! If I understood, next(iterators) is parsing the 'engine' which generates the iterators, where I want to parse the iterators themselves. Right?

Comment: Ok. I will take more time to understand what is going on. Now another question: why do the loop loops indefinitely while the integrators are consumed?

Comment: Sorry, I meant: after I fixed the code with your advice, the code still run in an infinite loop, even after all the iterables are consumed.

Comment: My first lesson learned is that map(func, x) intercepts StopIteration for its own use. A practical consequence is for map(next, x) because next is raising StopIteration but these are swallowed by map. The second lesson is more general: map(func, x) will consume x if x is a genarator. Consequently, repeated calls to map(f, generator) will fail, unless we do map(f, list(generator)). @shx2. Thank-you very much for your help and patience.